# How to reclaim storage from a column family in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am using Datastax 2.1 community version in EC2. I dropped a big table (column family) in a keyspace and ran "nodetool compact " but from OpsCenter UI, I don't see any increase in storage capacity.

I ran "nodetool compactionstats " to see whether compaction is on-going but there is nothing:
    $ nodetool compactionstats
    pending tasks: 0
    Active compaction remaining time :        n/a

Is there some other process I need to follow?

Comment: Are the sstable files still present on disk?

Comment: I see large files under datadirectory (keyspace/cf/snapshots/*). Are those sstable files?

Comment: Nope, these are snapshots (sort of sstable backups). Looks as if your cluster is configured to create a snapshot when dropping a cf. So the cf is removed but a snap of the same size is created. If you don't need the snapshot you can remove it (see http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsClearSnapShot.html )

Comment: That was it. Would you answer with your previous comment so that I can mark it as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra, in its default configuration, keeps a snapshot of every column family that is dropped. This is by design so you don't lose the data of a cf if you accidentally delete a cf.

You can disable the snapshot creation in `cassandra.yaml`. From the docs (see: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html ):

> auto_snapshot
>   (Default: true) Enable or disable whether a snapshot is
>   taken of the data before keyspace truncation or dropping of tables. To
>   prevent data loss, using the default setting is strongly advised. If
>   you set to false, you will lose data on truncation or drop.

If you don't disable auto snapshots you can remove the generated snapshot via `nodetool clearsnapshot`. See: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsClearSnapShot.html