# What's the function of snapshot in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, snapshot

Although I checked `Datastax`'s document about `snapshot`, I am still confused about what a `snapshot` in `cassandra` is. What's the function or main purpose of a `snapshot`?

Under the `snapshot` folder, I find some subfolder named in convention of this:

```
1426256545571-tablename
```

What does the number at the very beginning mean? Anyway, I just a need a easy way to know what a `snapshot` is.

Comment: A (possibly inconsistent, but repairable) backup. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/26200440/1686330

Comment: Means even I drop the current table, I can use the snapshot to recover the table to its original state?

Comment: Depends on your config (see my modified comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is the number of ms from epoch (`timestamp`). A snapshot is just a local backup. It occurs automatically for some types of operations like truncate (in case done by accident and want to undo it).

They are very fast and don't cost any extra disk space up front since its just a hard link to the immutable data files. Eventually you want to clean them up though to reclaim disk as compactions occur. You can disable the `auto_snapshot` option in `cassandra.yaml` if you don't want them anymore. It is likely you will see them while doing repairs, still.

Comment: Can I say it this way: for example, once I `drop` a table, it will move all the data files in that table to a newly created `ms-tablename` file?

Comment: yes, see

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/drop_table_r.html

    Dropping a table triggers an automatic snapshot, which backs up the data only, not the schema.